# Using AWSAppSyncClient inside an ECS Container (Fargate) with AWS_IAM auth mode - Returns 403 UnrecognizedClientException

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-appsync, aws-fargate, appsync-apollo-client

We have the following code in an ECS Fargate container however it is constantly returning an error.
When running identical code in a lambda with IAM authentication and the correct role setup, I am able to successfully run this.

#### Error

```
Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 403
UnrecognizedClientException
The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

#### Code

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import AWSAppSyncClient, { AUTH_TYPE } from 'aws-appsync';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

// Setup variables for client
const graphqlEndpoint = process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT;
const awsRegion = process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION;

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: graphqlEndpoint,
    region: awsRegion,
    auth: {
        type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM,
        credentials: AWS.config.credentials,
    },
    disableOffline: true,
})
```

#### Cloudformation

```
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Ommitted
      Cpu: !FindInMap [CpuMap, !Ref Cpu, Cpu]
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt "TaskExecutionRole.Arn"
      Family: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
      Memory: !FindInMap [MemoryMap, !Ref Memory, Memory]
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities: [FARGATE]
      TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt "TaskRole.Arn"
  TaskRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSAppSyncInvokeFullAccess" # Invoke Access for AppSync
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually discovered that this was a result of AppSyncClient not able to load the credentials in ECS correctly.

As per AWS Docs on [IAM roles in ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html), credentials are loaded different to other AWS services. Instead of credentials being populated in env vars, the Amazon ECS agent instead populated the `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` variable with a path to the credentials. I was able to successfully get `AWSAppSyncClient` working with `IAM` authenticaiton in an `ECS` container by first loading the `ECS` credentials manually and passing it to `AWSAppSyncClient`. The below example worked.

```
// AWSAppSyncClient needs to be provided ECS IAM credentials explicitly
const credentials = new AWS.ECSCredentials({
  httpOptions: { timeout: 50000 },
  maxRetries: 10,
});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

// Setup AppSync Config
const AppSyncConfig = {
  url: graphqlEndpoint,
  region: awsRegion,
  auth: {
    type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM,
    credentials: AWS.config.credentials,
  },
  disableOffline: true,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an expansion on the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68770377/5219886) with information regarding AWS SDK for JavaScript v3.

With v3 the `fromContainerMetadata()` method from the `@aws-sdk/credential-providers` package is used. See docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_credential_providers.html#fromcontainermetadata-and-frominstancemetadata).

Example usage:

```ts
import { fromContainerMetadata } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers"; // ES6 import
// const { fromContainerMetadata } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-providers"); // CommonJS import

const client = new FooClient({
  credentials: fromContainerMetadata({
    // Optional. The connection timeout (in milliseconds) to apply to any remote requests.
    // If not specified, a default value of `1000` (one second) is used.
    timeout: 1000,
    // Optional. The maximum number of times any HTTP connections should be retried. If not
    // specified, a default value of `0` will be used.
    maxRetries: 0,
  }),
});
```